# Unit test in reactive form - error on formBuilder

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I am new into unit test so my question may sound a bit noob. 
I have a reactive form in Angular 7 and I want to make my first unit test but I am stuck with an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

I initialize my form with:

```
public initForms (): void {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [tempData.id],
        firstName: [tempData.firstName],
        lastName: [tempData.lastName],
        company: [tempData.company]
    });
}
```

And in my test file I have:

```
describe('ContactListComponent', () => {
    let component: ContactListComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContactListComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule
            ],
            providers: [ {provide:FormBuilder}]
            declarations: [ContactListComponent]
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {

            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactListComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;

            component.initForms();
       });
    }));

     it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

If I remove the line  `component.initForms();` The single test will pass but now I want to start the real tests

Any help please,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `providers: [ {provide:FormBuilder}]` line from your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` call.

`FormBuilder` is already being provided by importing `ReactiveFormsModule`, so there's no need to provide it again.

If you do need to override a provider, use the syntax as specified here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#the-provider-object-literal

For example:

```
providers: [
  FormBuilder,
  { provide: FormBuilder, useClass: OtherFormBuilder },
  { provide: FormBuilder, useExisting: OtherFormBuilder },
  { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: otherFormBuilder },
  { provide: FormBuilder, useFactory: () => otherFormBuilder }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex k. I removed FormBuilder from providers and solved my problem. :)